# GetModuleFileName does not return the path of the calling program

Tags: windows, api

Why doesn't the following code print the path name of the calling program?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    cout << "Filepath:" << buffer << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What does GetLastError return?

Comment: what does it print ? Did you check GetLastError value ?

Comment: Btw, `sizeof(buffer)` is wrong. It must be `sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])` or just `MAX_PATH`. The function expects the size as the number of `TCHARs`. I wouldn't wonder if `std::cout` didn't support Unicode chars and strings by default.

Comment: cout is ASCI and TCHAR is most likely Unicode; it's only going to output the first character, probably the drive letter 'C'.

Comment: GetLastError returns 127. GetModuleFileName prints some hex value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, the problem was with cout, I used wprintf and it worked..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was breaking my head with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you don't see the content of the buffer (because of the fact that the application dies) but the buffer actually contains the data you expects?

Comment: setting a Breakpoint shows that buffer holds the complete path before cout executes, but I wonder why cout prints some hex value insted of printing the path??